# Blender - Smooth option?

Tags: blender, mesh

Is there a way to smooth those „cubes“ into straight line? I’m still new to blender.

[image]

Comment: Programmatically? Or are you just asking how to use Blender?

Comment: It's embarrassing, but yes i'm actually asking how to use Blender :D

Comment: You'll probably want a different site then; SO is specifically for programming questions, not software-unrelated-to-programming usage. Good luck! AFAIK there's a thriving Blender community forum.